# AWS Databrew DateTime format coversion error

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, datetime, datetime-format, aws-databrew

I've imported a CSV file in AWS Databrew. By default, it has converted every date-time column in string. I need to check whether a field is in date-time format or not. When I'm trying to convert "Source" column into "timeStamp" format, it's giving null, for fields having time(hours) in single digit. Can anyone pleae tell me how to resolve this issue ?

[image: conversion of Source col to the desired col.]